# WordPress image upload doesn't work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I trying to upload image into webhosting but it doesn't work..

I doing that in cooperation with plugin WooCommerce Product Addons, so I give new input to addon field (an image):

```
<input type="file" class="button" id="wc-pao-addon-img-first-<?php echo esc_attr( $loop ); ?>" name="product_addon_img_first[<?php echo esc_attr( $loop ); ?>]" accept="image/*" />
```

I added into `class-wc-product-addons-admin.php` into function `get_posted_product_addons()` these lines:

```
$addon_image_first        = $_FILES['product_addon_img_first'];
```

And I just make this block of code, in file class-wc-product-addons-admin.php:

```
require( ABSPATH.'wp-load.php' );

      $wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
      $i = 1;
      $photo = $addon_image_first;
      $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $photo['name'];
      $new_file_mime = mime_content_type( $photo['tmp_name'] );

      if( $photo['error'] )
          die( $photo['error'] );
    
    
      if( !in_array( $new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types() ) )
          die( 'WordPress doesn\'t allow this type of uploads.' );
    
      while( file_exists( $new_file_path ) ) {
          $i++;
          $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $i . '_' . $photo['name'];
      }

      // looks like everything is OK
      if( move_uploaded_file( $photo['tmp_name'], $new_file_path ) ) {
          $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
                'guid'           => $new_file_path, 
                'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
                'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $photo['name'] ),
                'post_content'   => '',
                'post_status'    => 'inherit'
          ), $new_file_path );

          // wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file
          require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

          // Generate and save the attachment metas into the database
          wp_update_attachment_metadata($upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, $new_file_path));
        
        $addon_image = $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $new_file_path ) ;
        
        echo $addon_image;


      }
```

But it doesn't works properly because the photography isn't saved into uploads folder

In DB postmeta table I have only name of the file, and it's just appended to every addon field, not only to the one, specific, the raw data:

```
a:16:{i:0;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:24:"Kempingový nábytek SET";s:12:"title_format";s:4:"hide";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"50 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:0;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:24:"Kempingový nábytek SET";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:1;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:37:"Držák 1 jízdního kola na střechu";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"25 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:1;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:37:"Držák 1 jízdního kola na střechu";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:2;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:28:"1x boční stěna k markýze";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"40 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:2;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:28:"1x boční stěna k markýze";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:3;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:32:"Nosič pro 2 jízdní kola na oj";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"50 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:3;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:32:"Nosič pro 2 jízdní kola na oj";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:4;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:28:"2x boční stěna k markýze";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"80 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:4;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:28:"2x boční stěna k markýze";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:5;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:32:"Nosič pro 3 jízdní kola na oj";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"80 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:5;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:32:"Nosič pro 3 jízdní kola na oj";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:6;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:38:"Přední stěna k markýze - jen k 480";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"60 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:6;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:38:"Přední stěna k markýze - jen k 480";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:7;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:17:"Nafukovací člun";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:11:"100 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:7;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:17:"Nafukovací člun";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:8;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:23:"Stanový přístřešek";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"90 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:8;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:23:"Stanový přístřešek";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:9;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:18:"El. motor k člunu";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:11:"100 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:9;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:18:"El. motor k člunu";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:10;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:30:"Malý gril na dřevěné uhlí";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"10 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:10;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:30:"Malý gril na dřevěné uhlí";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:11;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:23:"Toaletní papír navíc";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:11:"20 Kč/role";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:11;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:23:"Toaletní papír navíc";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:12;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:13:"Plynový gril";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"40 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:12;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:13:"Plynový gril";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:13;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:12:"GPS navigace";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:10:"80 Kč/den";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:13;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:12:"GPS navigace";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}i:14;a:19:{s:4:"name";s:25:"Rezervní láhev PB 10 kg";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:1;s:11:"description";s:6:"Zdarma";s:9:"img_first";a:5:{s:4:"name";a:16:{i:0;s:37:"Royalvape_KORUNA_VELKY-ZLUTA_seda.png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:4:"type";a:16:{i:0;s:9:"image/png";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:8:"tmp_name";a:16:{i:0;s:47:"/data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/tmp/phpLtY1PX";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";i:5;s:0:"";i:6;s:0:"";i:7;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:10;s:0:"";i:11;s:0:"";i:12;s:0:"";i:13;s:0:"";i:14;s:0:"";i:15;s:0:"";}s:5:"error";a:16:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:4;i:3;i:4;i:4;i:4;i:5;i:4;i:6;i:4;i:7;i:4;i:8;i:4;i:9;i:4;i:10;i:4;i:11;i:4;i:12;i:4;i:13;i:4;i:14;i:4;i:15;i:4;}s:4:"size";a:16:{i:0;i:36373;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;i:10;i:0;i:11;i:0;i:12;i:0;i:13;i:0;i:14;i:0;i:15;i:0;}}s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:6:"select";s:8:"position";i:14;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:25:"Rezervní láhev PB 10 kg";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}s:32:"wc_booking_person_qty_multiplier";i:0;s:31:"wc_booking_block_qty_multiplier";i:0;}}
```

The errors in debug.log are:

```
[13-Jun-2021 18:58:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/www/domains/fkcommercium.cz/book/ajax.php on line 3
```

and:

```
[13-Jun-2021 18:58:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments in /data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/www/domains/fkcommercium.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/includes/admin/class-wc-product-addons-admin.php on line 426
```

Comment: did you searched the image elsewhere on the server ? also did you check server error log ?

Comment: Hello, any image wasn't uploaded anywhere as I checked, but the debug log shows mi these erros: `[13-Jun-2021 18:58:10 UTC] PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/www/domains/fkcommercium.cz/book/ajax.php on line 3
[13-Jun-2021 18:58:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments in /data/web/virtuals/276524/virtual/www/domains/fkcommercium.cz/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-product-addons/includes/admin/class-wc-product-addons-admin.php on line 426`

Comment: well it seems you have your answer in the log, you should try to look why the `mime_content_type()` function is getting the wrong value